Can WordPress handle tens of thousands of pages/posts on a single site?
I am a beginner trying to learn how to turn a WordPress site into a digital archive. I will need to create permalinks for potentially tens of thousands of documents in this archive. I'm hoping someone here could help me come up with a feasible plan so that I'll know what I need to study to pull this off.
Currently, I have two strategies in mind:

Using the WordPress commandline app, I could create a page/post for every single document in the archive. I'm not sure how to do this yet, but I think I could use Apache Solr to build in an advanced search function. I'm hoping with sufficient metadata, having this many discrete pages will still be navigable. But I am worried that having this many pages or posts will be unmanageable on both the admin and user side.

Or, I create a single display page in combination with a database of XML metadata files. Using xquery/xpath, the user could query the documents they need and the metadata and object would show up on the display page. I'm not sure how to create permalinks with this strategy yet, though, or if it's even possible.


Are either of these strategies reasonable? Or is there a better strategy I haven't thought of? Any advice would be much appreciated. And please forgive my lack of fluency with programmer lingo. I hope my explanation above is clear.

I think you may be better served using something resembling a database like Solr or Elasticsearch if your needs goes into the tens of thousands.  And then the "website" can dynamically pull data from the database as requested and display it like a webpage.

When you say "document," do you mean text or images (like of historical documents)? Not that either is likely to create terrible difficulties for WordPress, or, more precisely, MySQL, in modern environments, but it might be helpful to know.

To clarify, each item in the archive will have an XML metadata file associated with the item itself, whether it be a PDF, image, video, or whatever. So, ideally, when querying an item, it would pull both the metadata and the item to display on the page. Or I would have both saved on a page/post and the search would pull up the specific page rather than pulling data and objects from the database. I hope that makes a little more sense.
